# how to use a 'not_if' condition on a template resource

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, cookbook, chef-template

I'm trying to use a 'not_if' condition in a template resource as showcased by [docs.chef.io](https://docs.chef.io/resource_template.html)

```
template "/tmp/somefile" do
  mode '0644'
  source "somefile.erb"
  not_if { node[:some_value] }
end
```

I'm new to chef and I'm unsure how to proceed to create something that effectively does the following:

```
if 'instance' (in node['project']['instance']) == nil 
do NOT do anything for this template
```

I would like to use the not_if condition but I don't know how to check for 'instance' == nil.

I would appreciate any help.
Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

how about

```
not_if { node['project']['instance'].nil? }
```

This will check that the value of node['project']['instance'] is not nil.  It will also fail if node['project'] happens to be nil, so if you aren't sure, you'll need:

```
not_if { node['project'].nil? || node['project']['instance'].nil? }
```

Comment: Mind to explain this a bit? ;)

Comment: wouldn't this check if ['project']['instance'] combined equal nil? what if 'project != nil but 'instance' == nil?

Comment: Got the following error:   ArgumentError
-------------
Invalid only_if/not_if command: true (TrueClass)

Comment: Sorry David, I forgot the `{}` around it (the method wants a block).